# Typescript class with index signature from passed type

Tags: typescript, index-signature

I'm new to typescript and I'm trying to define a class properly that turns an object of a certain type to a class with the same properties. However, I can't properly define the keys on this class since they are generic:

```js
interface RawAnswer {
  __typename: string;
  id: string;
  meta: Record<string, unknown>;
}

class TrackedAnswer<T> {
  // This doesn't work:
  // [K in keyof T]: T<K>

  constructor(obj: T) {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      // this is just an example, I'm aware that this is useless
      this[key] = value;
    });
  }
}

const raw: RawAnswer = { __typename: "StringAnswer", id: "123", meta: {} };
const answer = new TrackedAnswer(raw);
```

I'd like the `TrackedAnswer` class to have the same index signature as `RawAnswer` in this case. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I've found my self needing this pattern multiple times, this is how is solved it:

```
class TrackedAnswer<T extends TrackedAnswer<T>> {
  constructor(e: T) {
    Object.keys(e).forEach((k) => {
      // @ts-ignore
      this[k] = e[k];
    });
  }
}

class Answer extends TrackedAnswer<Answer> {
  public __typename!: string;
  public id!: string;
  public meta!: Record<string, unknown>;
}

const raw: Answer = { __typename: "StringAnswer", id: "123", meta: {} };
const answer = new Answer(raw);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqBOZgGsCmATAggOwgd1XgB5ZpUAPAF1W3RgSTS1wONgD53oBvAKGmjAA9rkrwArsEpD4AClQAuOAEoe-AdADyAIwBWqKQDo0ATwjzlhgGYyAokgAWs2clUBeLnw0aA9D+gAApQQALQAlgDm2DKo6t6UDmEQANrIALrQbmSpaQDccdAAvsr5AoW85bygkDA4+IRkVDR0cIgoGHWsRJ2EnuoADuLaIGHA0AD645Qm-TRgALaoAIRKEGJh2BGl0IPDo9Bh6CvQa-AbWwNDI2OLlGDHAEoGMuhEp+cANNDi2MjReNh2PlKsJRNBEHglD14JkeBMpjM5oslAAiADK6020JRX0OqIAjAAmADMOOgtzASm4hSK+VBa2gYBYDSy2FQeGg0NkEJKQA)

It's also included in my typescript helper library if you want to use it thrugh npm: https://github.com/Olian04/typescript-helpers/blob/master/src/lib/record.ts

Comment: So there's no way around an intermediate class just for adapting the proper types?

Comment: @JonasMetzener there might be. But this is how i solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get auto-completion and have the class satisfy the interface with a static factory and cast:

```
interface RawAnswer {
  __typename: string;
  id: string;
  meta: Record<string, unknown>;
}

class TrackedAnswer<T> {

  constructor(obj: T) {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      (this as any)[key] = value;
    });
  }
}

function trackedAnswerFactory<T>(obj: T) {
    return new TrackedAnswer(obj) as TrackedAnswer<T> & T;
}

const raw: RawAnswer = { __typename: "StringAnswer", id: "123", meta: {} };
const answer = trackedAnswerFactory(raw);

const iOnlyAcceptRawAnswer = (a: RawAnswer) => console.log("This is a RawAnswer");

iOnlyAcceptRawAnswer(answer);
```